# Better way to create signature for preview than holding a paper in front of the camera

Tags: preview, signature

I have a perfectly fine scanned image of a signature.  It is unnecessarily inaccurate  to hold it in front of the camera instead of using the image directly.

How to enter the signature from the image file directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done directly.

Best authority I can find to back up this statement is Linc Davis, on the Apple Support Communities. - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3667416

It is possible to create one that way in Acrobat Pro/DC, but I'm not then certain if that would then also work in Preview. It would depend if Acrobat creates the signature as a true Keychain Signature item.

It's not clear from [Acrobat Help / 
Sign PDF documents](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/signing-pdfs.html) but implies Adobe use their own cloud service to keep tabs on signatures rather than the Keychain.

Comment: How about just copying an image from the clipboard?? Well in any case i am going to ask a separate question for that.

Comment: the only 2 ways to get a signature directly into Preview are 1) camera & 2) copy the Keychain entry from one Mac to another. That's it. Acrobat will import an image, but I don't think that is portable to Preview.